# Problems running Swing application with IDEA 8M1

Tags: java, swing, ide, jvm, intellij-idea

Is anyone else having trouble running Swing applications from IntelliJ IDEA 8 Milestone 1?  Even the simplest application of showing an empty JFrame seems to crash the JVM.  I don't get a stack trace or anything, it looks like the JVM itself crashes and Windows shows me a pop-up that says the usual "This process is no longer responding" message.

Console applications work fine, and my Swing code works fine when launching from Netbeans or from the command line. I'm running Windows Vista x64 with the JDK 1.6 Update 10 beta, which may be a configuration the Jetbrains guys haven't run into yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually experienced problems from using the JDK 6u10 beta myself and had to downgrade to JDK 6u7 for the time being. This solved some of my problems with among other things swing.

Also, i have been running IJ8M1 since the 'release' and I am very satisfied with it, especially if you regard the "beta" tag. It feels snappier and also supports multiple cores which makes my development machine rejoice. ;p

Anyway, i use WinXP32 and IJ8M1 with JDK 6u7 and that is afaik very stable indeed.

Comment: By the way, JDK 6u10 became stable today, i will check it out and so should you! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ask your question directly on the IDEA website. They always react fast and the problem you have is probably either fixed or documented.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA 8 Milestone 1 is a beta(ish) "based on a new platform". This may have changed the way that swing is handled. Also you are running a beta JDK.

You will probably get more help/submit a bug at the Jetbrain forums unless they are on SO also. [Here is the bug tracker link](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/IDEA/)